# Deleting large number of duplicates in attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, delete, duplicates

In QGIS 3.22 I have a vector file with about 9000+ objects and for some reason, each of them has duplicates. Which way can I find on QGIS to remove duplicates which have the same object `"ID"` (ID= code with numbers) (but keep of course at least one of them...)

Comment: Are you asking how the tools `delete duplicate geometries` and `remove duplicates by attributes` work?

Comment: Hi, I did not know those tools, "delete duplicate geometries worked" not the other one, thank you a lot!

Comment: It worked on one of my vector but not an other one...nothing is happening :(

Comment: I suppose you need to provide example data.